# How do I initiate a clean windows shutdown without waiting for a user?

Tags: c++, console-application, windows-embedded

I'm trying to make an embedded windows 7 application shut the machine down gracefully.

I've tried this:

```
ExitWindowsEx(EWX_POWEROFF | EWX_FORCE,
        SHTDN_REASON_MAJOR_OPERATINGSYSTEM |
        SHTDN_REASON_MINOR_UPGRADE |
        SHTDN_REASON_FLAG_PLANNED);
```

which appears to instantly kill everything (my app doesn't exit cleanly, it just dies).

I've tried swapping `EWX_FORCE` for `EWX_FORCEIFHUNG` but that presents the user with a dialog which, in contrast to [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376868%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) doesn't seem to offer any timeout.

Is there a way of doing this elegently or do I simply need to record the need to shutdown and then call the forcible shutdown as the last thing my app does?

Comment: Hmm. Your linked page says "*If the EWX_FORCEIFHUNG value is specified, the system forces hung applications to close and does not display the dialog box.*".

Comment: Yes indeed but that does not appear to be what windows does.

Comment: How do you know your program doesn't exit cleanly? What's the exit code?

Comment: Logs finish abruptly but that's a good point; I should check the exit code to double-check whether this is an issue from the logging rather than the shutdown mechanism.